# Is there a way to float a button and text above a loader?

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to position two buttons in the bottom left corner of the website along with a heading in the top left corner. However, ive imported a 3D model and despite it being located in the centre of the page, a part of it (im guessing the background) seems to be covering the button I aleady have in place. I was wondering if it is possible to either float the buttons and text above the model or position the model inside something to set it's size to stop it overlapping the button.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated as I am a novice.

The code I have so far can be seen below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#button').click(function() {
    $('blood.DAE').toggle();
});



});
</script>

<title>Visualising Cells</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button type="button">Load Red Blood Cell</button>


<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
camera.position.z = 0.16;
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
scene.add(camera);


var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width,height); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene,camera);
renderer.setClearColor("rgb(255,255,255)");

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
        scene.add(light);



var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('blood.DAE', function (collada) {

            object = collada.scene;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.updateMatrix();
            scene.add(object);
            }
            );



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
console.log(camera.position.z);
if (event.keyCode == 38) {

    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;

    }

}

else if (event.keyCode == 40) {

    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

    if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
    }

    }
}, true);

render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

object.rotation.x += 0.01;
object.rotation.y += 0.01;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        render();


</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

id="BottomLeftButton" <-- add that to your button

and this to your css

```
#BottomLeftButton{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px
  left:0px;
}
```

add other attributes you want (or if you have already got a selector just add the above to it)

the css will "fix" your button to the bottom left of its container :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttons you need floated inside a fixed-position div.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .float-btn{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 1%;
        left: 2%;
    }
</style>

<div class="float-btn">
    <button type="button">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
    <button type="button">Another Button</button>
</div>
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0kc4hr3/3/)

Comment: Thankyou for your quick replay, it works perfectly! I am also wondering if it is possible to use jquery to assign each of the 3D models to each of the buttons, i've had a go in the code posted in the question but i'm not sure how to select the model, do i need to select the model it's self (blood.DAE), the renderer or the loader?

Comment: @G.Smith That question seems a bit outside the scope for the html and css tags you put on the question. You might get better answers by asking a separate question with a three.js, webgl, or collada tag on it.